# Difference between Haskell's Lazy and Strict monads (or transformers)

Tags: haskell, monads, lazy-evaluation

When browsing Hackage, most of the monads have a Lazy and a Strict version. What is the difference exactly? Can you highlight it with some examples for the common monads (State, Reader, Writer)?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I don't know of a separation into lazy and strict for the reader monad, the reason for the `State(T)` and `Writer(T)` separation doesn't apply there.

The difference between the lazy and strict `Writer` and `State` monads resp. their monad transformers is the implementation of the monadic bind `(>>=)`, `fmap` etc. In the strict versions, the implementation pattern-matches on the pair (`(result, state)`, resp. `(result, message)`), forcing its evaluation (**not** the evaluation of its components), while the lazy versions use an irrefutable pattern `~(a,w)` there, which does not force the evaluation of the pair.

The lazy versions allow some applications that are not possible for the strict versions, e.g.

```
foo = do
    xs <- take 100 `fmap` sequence (repeat someAction)
    doSomethingWith xs
```

the `sequence` of an infinite list of actions can only start delivering its result if the `(>>=)` of the monad is sufficiently lazy.

On the other hand, using the lazy versions often leads to the build-up of large thunks in the `(result, state)` pairs, and thus to space and/or time leaks.

So both variants are offered, and you can choose which suits your needs better.

Comment: For the interested, the possible side-effects in the monad might still be strict, though. See for instance [this gist](https://gist.github.com/obscaenvs/b2ae2264fe118ac5db77)
(investigates the strictness of the state in the state monad, needlessly MD)