# Evaluation of 'and' clause with regards to laziness

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I don't understand why the following code behaves the way it does:

```
myand :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
myand True True = True
myand _ _ = False

containsAandB :: String -> IO Bool
containsAandB s = do
  containsA <- do
    putStrLn $ "Check if 'a' is in " ++ s
    return $ 'a' `elem` s
  containsB <- do
    putStrLn $ "Check if 'b' is in " ++ s
    return $ 'b' `elem` s
  return $ containsA `myand` containsB
```

This is the output when I test the function:

```
*Main> containsAandB "def"
Check if 'a' is in def
Check if 'b' in in def
False
```

Note that (&&) behaves just like 'myand', I just wrote a custom function to better visualize what's happeninig.
I'm surprised about the `'Check if 'b' is in def` part since `containsA` is already false so 'myand' can be evaluated regardless of `containsB`.

**Question 1:**
Is there a particular reason why `containsB` has to be evaluated too? My understanding was that the `containsB <- do ...` statement is not evaluated unless it's required but my guess is that this might behave differently since it's IO and therefore not free of side effects?

**Question2:**
What's the best practice approach to get the desired behavior (if `containsA` is false, `containsB` is not checked) without dealing with nested `if-else` clauses?

Comment: Well you wrap it in an `IO` monad, so due to the monad.

Comment: Okay, so my assumption was correct that it behaves this way because it's not side-effect free? I'm so sorry but this comment is a bit too vague for me to understand.

Comment: Well imagine that your two elements `containsA` and `containsB` read from a file. Then they advance the cursor. Now that means that depending of the value of `containsA` the cursor will (or will not) advance? That is behavior one typically wants to avoid. So the `IO` actions are guaranteed to take place if they are in the monad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Question 1:**
>   Is there a particular reason why containsB has to be evaluated too? My understanding was that the containsB <- do ... statement is not evaluated unless it's required but my guess is that this might behave differently since it's IO and therefore not free of side effects?

Your experiment is flawed because you perform `IO`. One of the important aspects of `IO` is that the order of `IO` statements is respected. So even if due to lazyness, we do not need a certain value, the `IO` part is executed.

This is logical in the world of `IO`: imagine that we read a file, and we have three parts. We read the first two parts, and then we read the third one. But now imagine that due to laziness, the second `IO` command is never executed. Then that would mean that third part actually reads the second part of the file.

So in short **due to `IO`, the statements *are* evaluated**. But only the `IO` statements. So the value wrapped inside the `return` is *not* evaluated, unless you need it. The check `` 'b' `elem` s `` only happens when we need it.

There are however ways to "*trick*" the `IO` out of this. For example `trace` (from the `Debug.Trace`) module will perform "*unsafe IO*": it will print the error message given it is evaluated. If we write:

```
Prelude> import Debug.Trace
Prelude Debug.Trace> myand (trace "a" False) (trace "b" False)
```

we got:

```
Prelude Debug.Trace> myand (trace "a" False) (trace "b" False)
a
False
```

> **Question2:**
>   What's the best practice approach to get the desired behavior (if containsA is false, containsB is not checked) without dealing with nested if-else clauses?

Well as said before, normal behavior is that `containsB` is *not* evaluated. But if you perform `IO` actions, those *have* to be performed before you actually do the checking. This is bascially one of the aspects that the `(>>=)` operator for `IO` (you use this operator implcitly in a `do` block) handles.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you!

Comment: The terminology is all wrong. There is no "an `IO` monad". The `IO` type itself is a monad (`IO` is also a functor). When you have a `do` block, that's not a monad; that's just a value of type `IO something`.

Comment: @melpomene: well not really, a `do` block can lead to any `Monad m => m something`. It is only the type checking that convert it to a specific `m`. If at all, for example `liftM2 h f g = do {x <- f; y <- g; return h x y}` has a type `Monad m => (a -> b -> c) -> m a -> m b -> m c`.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about `do` blocks doing I/O specifically. But even in general, the `do` block itself is not "a monad"; the "monad" part is specifically the `m` in the type signature.

Comment: @melpomene: yes, I know, but it makes it a little bit "chaotic" to talk about monads. So typically in discussions with friends, collegues, etc. I use "shortcuts", although those are understood by collegues, I guess it can be confusing :).

Comment: I think these shortcuts might actually make it harder to explain why the versions in my answer _do_ work :)

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: well they should have defenestrated the person who introduced things like `State` and `IO`, since actually those things are not `State` or `IO`, they describe *changes* in states and IO. I think I would probably explain it as "*defining two `IO`s, and one is guarded by* encoding *the function into an outher `IO`*". So basically guarding the IO.

Answer (score 3):

`do` blocks get translated into calls to `>>=` and `>>`. In particular, your code becomes (unless I missed some parentheses)

```
containsAandB s = 
  (putStrLn $ "Check if 'a' is in " ++ s >>
   return $ 'a' `elem` s) >>= (\containsA ->
  (putStrLn $ "Check if 'b' is in " ++ s >>
   return $ 'b' `elem` s) >>= (\containsB ->
  return $ containsA `myand` containsB))
```

So `containsB <- do ...` isn't really a *statement*; it makes the `do ...` part the first argument to a `>>=` call. And `>>=` (and `>>`) for `IO` is defined so it always runs its first argument. So to get to the last `return $ ...`, both `putStrLn` calls already must have run.

This behavior isn't limited to the IO monad; e.g. see [Difference between Haskell's Lazy and Strict monads (or transformers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186512/difference-between-haskells-lazy-and-strict-monads-or-transformers).

> What's the best practice approach to get the desired behavior (if containsA is false, containsB is not checked) without dealing with nested if-else clauses?

You can deal with them once and for all:

```
andM :: (Monad m) => m Boolean -> m Boolean -> m Boolean
andM m1 m2 = do
  x <- m1
  case x of
    True -> m2
    False -> return False

containsAandB s = andM
  (do
    putStrLn $ "Check if 'a' is in " ++ s
    return $ 'a' `elem` s)
  (do
    putStrLn $ "Check if 'b' is in " ++ s
    return $ 'b' `elem` s)
```

or

```
containsAandB :: String -> IO Bool
containsAandB s = do
  let containsA = do
    putStrLn $ "Check if 'a' is in " ++ s
    return $ 'a' `elem` s
  let containsB = do
    putStrLn $ "Check if 'b' is in " ++ s
    return $ 'b' `elem` s
  containsA `andM` containsB
```

(`andM` is in http://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.6.8/docs/Control-Monad-Extra.html as `(&&^)`, along with other similar functions).