# A lazy version of liftM2

Tags: haskell, monads, lazy-evaluation

To answer [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50783116/evaluation-of-and-clause-with-regards-to-laziness/50783532), I wrote

```
andM :: (Monad m) => m Boolean -> m Boolean -> m Boolean
andM m1 m2 = do
  x <- m1
  case x of
    True -> m2
    False -> return False
```

which doesn't evaluate `m2` if not necessary, unlike `liftM2 (&&) m1 m2` (in `IO`).

Is there a way to write `liftM2Lazy` with the same type as `liftM2` (or more restricted in some way?) which preserves laziness in general? So that e.g. `liftM2Lazy (&&)` is indistinguishable from `andM`, `liftM2Lazy (||)` from `orM` (with the obvious definition), etc.?

Comment: Have a look at `ifM`, `eitherM` and friends. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.6.8/docs/Control-Monad-Extra.html

Comment: Yes, I've seen that module while trying to answer for myself. I've edited the question to clarify it.

Comment: Looks to me that this is impossible, at least in general. Imagine that this is not `IO`, but `[]`, then we start adding only one element in case the second parameter is not needed for the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible in general -- it requires a source-to-source translation to lift lazy functions to lazy monadic functions.

For `IO` specifically, and where one knows in advance *which* arguments a function is lazy in (and how "deeply" lazy it is -- that is, how far into the returned structure one needs to evaluate to discover whether one needs to execute the other action), one can use `IO`'s exception-catching and `unsafeInterleave`ing powers to write a generic lifting function. But such functions are so specific and so easy to use incorrectly that I suspect you're better off not writing them at all.

Comment: I see, thanks. I expected that was the answer at the beginning, now I wonder how to prove it's impossible...

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible for general monads, but for the specific case of `IO` it can be achieved pretty easily (and comparatively safely) by using `unsafeInterleaveIO`, which turns an IO action lazy:

```
import System.IO.Unsafe

liftIO2Lazy :: (a -> b -> c) -> IO a -> IO b -> IO c
liftIO2Lazy f io1 io2 = do
    x <- unsafeInterleaveIO io1
    y <- unsafeInterleaveIO io2
    return $ f x y
```

The result will be lazy in exactly the same arguments, in which `f` is lazy, so it works even for functions that don't follow the same left-to-right short-circuit logic as `&&` and `||`:

```
ioTrue = putStrLn "TRUE" >> return True
ioFalse = putStrLn "FALSE" >> return False

liftIO2Lazy (&&) ioTrue ioFalse
-- Prints both messages
liftIO2Lazy (||) ioTrue ioFalse
-- Only prints TRUE
liftIO2Lazy (flip (||)) ioTrue ioFalse
-- Only prints FALSE
liftIO2Lazy (const (const 42)) ioTrue ioFalse
-- No output
```

Comment: Nice! Is there a class of monads for which it's possible, or is it only `IO`?

Answer (score 0):

An approach using [spoon](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/spoon-0.3.1), which is a bit of cheating:

```
liftM2Lazy f m1 m2 =
  case teaspoon $ f undefined undefined of
    Just res -> return res
    Nothing ->
      do x1 <- m1
         case teaspoon $ f x1 undefined of
           Just res -> return res
           Nothing ->
             do x2 <- m2
                return $ f x1 x2
```

Comment: And here you see what I mean by the fragility comments in my answer: this works okay for `(&&)`, but is not as lazy as it could be for `flip (&&)`. And for something like `zip`, the analysis is even more complicated...